# How to get attachment in EWS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get attachment from exchange; I am getting file name and other details. However, I don't want to store the attachment physically; instead whenever attachment containing mail gets open; then attachment name should be shown and after clicking on it actual attachment should get retrieved. So, here I can show the option Open/Save file(a regular windows explorer window).

My question is how can I do this ? Below is code that I worked upon; But didn't find for what I am looking for.

```
if (blnHasAttachments && email.Attachments[0] is FileAttachment)
            {

                ContentID = email.Attachments[0].ContentId;

                FileAttachment fileattachment = email.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
                fileattachment.Load();
            }
```

Any help on this appreciated !